# Android Action Bar (Sherlock Action Bar) - Position the drop-down spinner all the way to the right

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

Is there any way to change the position of the drop-down spinner in the action bar?

I've found this style for the spinner-drop down:

```
    <style name="Sherlock.__Widget.Holo.Spinner" parent="Widget">
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/abs__list_selector_holo_dark</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/abs__menu_dropdown_panel_holo_dark</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownVerticalOffset">0dip</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownHorizontalOffset">0dip</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownWidth">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">left|center_vertical</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerMode">dropdown</item>
    <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
</style>
```

...but how do I make this spinner go all the way to the right of the action bar?  Right now it looks like this....

[image: Example Activity]

I'd like for the spinner to sit flush against the right side of the action bar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

The only way to do this would be to use a custom navigation where you give it your own `Spinner`. Then you can set the gravity to the right on the `ActionBar.LayoutParams`. This will move the custom view to the right of the screen (but it will still remain to the left of the action items).

Comment: That is what I ended up doing.  It seems as though the space all the way to the right is always reserved for the action items even if you don't use it.